# Error on Select statement within SQL cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

I have altered the below SQL from a similar statement, but for some reason this version will not work.

It keeps returning the error:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.

Here is the code:

```
DECLARE @tablevalue NVARCHAR(max), 
        @sql        NVARCHAR(max); 
DECLARE table_value_cursor CURSOR FOR 
  SELECT DISTINCT [tariff lookup] 
  FROM   [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-05-31-2014-05-01-customer325]; 

OPEN table_value_cursor 

FETCH next FROM table_value_cursor INTO @tablevalue 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
  BEGIN 
      SELECT @sql = N'UPDATE [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-05-31-2014-05-01-customer325] SET [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-05-31-2014-05-01-customer325].[Sell Price] = ROUND ([Orbisrates].[dbo].' + @tablevalue 
                    + 
'.[Peakperminute]/60*[OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-05-31-2014-05-01-customer325].[ChargedTimeSecs]+[Orbisrates].[dbo].' 
       + @tablevalue 
       + 
'.[Peakconnect],4) INNER JOIN [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-05-31-2014-05-01-customer325] on [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-05-31-2014-05-01-customer325].[ChargeCode] = [Orbisrates].[dbo].' 
       + @tablevalue 
       + 
'.[Chargecode] WHERE [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-05-31-2014-05-01-customer325].[tariff lookup] = ''' 
       + @tablevalue + ''''; 

    EXEC Sp_executesql 
      @sql; 

    FETCH next FROM table_value_cursor INTO @tablevalue; 
END 

CLOSE table_value_cursor 

DEALLOCATE table_value_cursor;
```

Can anyone help me with the correct syntax?

Comment: As the statement suggests, something is wrong near the keyword 'INNER'. A good start would be to write out the UPDATE statement inside the dynamic SQL part of your code, and then examine what's wrong (hint: It has something to do with missing a FROM-clause).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the `FROM TABLE` in your UPDATE Statement before the INNER JOIN

The statement should be like this:

```
SELECT @sql = N'UPDATE [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-05-31-2014-05-01-customer325] SET [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-05-31-2014-05-01-customer325].[Sell Price] =
ROUND ([Orbisrates].[dbo].'+ @tablevalue +'.[Peakperminute]/60*[OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-05-31-2014-05-01-customer325].[ChargedTimeSecs]+[Orbisrates].[dbo].'+ @tablevalue +'.[Peakconnect],4)
FROM [Orbisrates].[dbo].'+@tablevalue+' 
INNER JOIN [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-05-31-2014-05-01-customer325] on [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-05-31-2014-05-01-customer325].[ChargeCode] = [Orbisrates].[dbo].'+ @tablevalue +'.[Chargecode]
WHERE [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-05-31-2014-05-01-customer325].[tariff lookup] = '''+ @tablevalue +'''';
```